# PyCharm won't autocomplete method from imported class

Tags: python, oop, autocomplete, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Running PyCharm on Mac OS X 10.11.6

I have a class `FruitShop` in shop.py with a method getPriceOfOrder(self, orderList)

I have a class `shopSmart` in shopSmart.py

Before declaring `shopSmart`, I import `shop`.

I instantiate a `FruitShop: shop1` in `shopSmart` and I call `shop1.getPriceOfOrder(orders).`

When I type this line, PyCharm's autocomplete does not suggest `getPriceOfOrder()` to me. Is there anyway to implement this feature?

The code works as expected, it's just the PyCharm autocomplete that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sometimes auto-complete may work sometimes it may not. There are a lot of variables that could be causing your undesired behavior. But the important thing, as you already mentioned, is that **your code works**. Remember, its the code that is important not the IDE.

Comment: The module name `shopSmart.py` is conflicting with the function `shopSmart()` defined in it. It is maybe what is confusing the autocomplete algorithm. AFAIR there is no class `shopSmart` in Berkeley's CS188 tutorial.